# What's the nohup on Windows?

Tags: windows, nohup

I want to run a Java jar file like this:

```
java -jar spider.jar
```

How to run it on the background on Windows?

Like this on Linux:

```
nohup java -jar spider.jar > /var/tmp/spider.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536205/running-another-program-in-windows-bat-file-and-not-create-child-process

Answer (score 30, accepted):

On Windows it's not normal that a process terminates once its parent was killed (like Unix-likes do it normally). Therefore there is no direct necessity for something like `nohup`. If you want to avoid the console window associated with it, you can use `javaw` but redirection won't work, then.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997718/difference-between-java-exe-and-javaw-exe

Comment: There is a case where you need a windows equivalent of nohup: things launched with the windows "start" command are killed when you log out.

Comment: @Anthony: All processes belonging to your user are killed when you log out. Note also that `start` is a command of `cmd.exe`, not of Windows.

Comment: @Joey **but redirection won't work** what do you mean by this?

Comment: @Vikash: `javaw` is a GUI program, it doesn't automatically have an attached console. Hence you cannot redirect the standard streams like stdout.

Comment: On some Windows 10 version:
c:\>which start
C:/PROGRA~2/INTEGR~1/Toolkit/mksnt/start.exe

Answer (score 34):

You could use the Windows `start` command:

```
start /min java -jar spider.jar
```

This command is not really the same as `nohup`; but it might be suitable if you're happy with the Java process running in a separate minimised window. See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx

Comment: combining javaw with start we can get rid of minimised window too.  start javaw -jar spider.jar

Comment: What about an analogue for powershell?

Answer (score 7):

The only way to get the nohup behavior, where the process still runs after logging off (like for micro-services, analytic tools, server batch jobs etc.), is to run the .bat file with the  `start javaw -jar ...` contents as either a service or a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1):

save the following code to `nohup.vbs`, and add the directory to PATH.

```vb
Set args=Wscript.Arguments
Set ws=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
ws.Run args(0),0,true
```

then, run:

```
nohup "java -jar spider.jar > /var/tmp/spider.log"
```

Note that you **should quote the full commands and the redirects**.

Comment: what does this keyword mean: 'ture' ?

Comment: @AlexanderStohr sorry, that's a spelling mistake.

Answer (score -3):

For windows run following mentioned command in Command Prompt or in Terminal

nohup (file need to run) > (File you need to save the log) 2>&1

Ex:
nohup ./bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties > ./MyKafka.log 2>&1