# Launching Sublime Text detached from MSYS bash on Windows

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, bash

Bash is my shell on Windows. How do I launch Sublime Text from the MSYS bash prompt detached from the console similar to launching it using "start /i " on a regular DOS prompt? This is my alias line in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
```

But this does not detach from the console and I have to close the Sublime Text window or run a new console instance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382082/whats-the-nohup-on-windows similar question

Comment: I guess you could add `&` at the end of the alias.