# Close cmd without interrupting python script

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

I have a python script that needs to be run from cmd, but should also stay running once the cmd window has been closed. I've tried various combinations of `START` and `CALL` but I've hit a mental blank (and google isn't helping at all).

Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
start /b python server.py
start python client-sendmessage.py
exit
```

`server.py` is a singleton, and should continue running after `exit` is reached. `client-sendmessage.py` should halt the script until it returns.

Comment: Changing the script to `.pyw` doesn't create a console window. And check http://stackoverflow.com/q/21031171/236871

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382082/whats-the-nohup-on-windows

Comment: Continue to use `start /b` and have server.py run `import ctypes; if ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(): ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeConsole()`. server.py will continue to run until the user's session ends. If you need it to continue running after the user logs off, then implement server.py as a service that runs in session 0.

Comment: thank you @eryksun, that worked a charm! for what it's worth, freeing the console will cause `print()` to throw a `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` error. i literally spent 2 hours debugging before i finally commented my print statements out..

Comment: Yes, if the process detaches from the console the existing stdin, stdout, and stderr file descriptors (i.e. descriptors 0, 1, 2) are invalid because the OS handles for `CONIN$` and `CONOUT$` are no longer valid. You can rebind `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to log files, but it would be better to just use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. You can also use a command line `--debug` argument to have the server remain attached to the console for printing debug messages.

Comment: thanks for the information. this is my first python project and your wisdom has been invaluable. i ended up using the logging module which saved me plenty of hair follicles.. [here's](https://github.com/MGinshe/ftp-push-changes.py) my project if you're interested, it's a batch ftp uploader that only pushes files that have been modified.