# Open Shh and start exe in the background

Tags: ssh

We need to install the EXE on the remote computer. I want to open the SSH connection remotely and run the EXE file. It succeeded. However, when I close the SSH connection, the EXE will be killed. Is there a 'nohup' command similar to linux to solve this problem in windows. I tried start /b and start /b without success.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I close the SSH connection, the EXE will be killed.

Double-check that: as explained in "[What's the `nohup` on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3382087/6309)":

> On Windows it's not normal that a process terminates once its parent was killed (like Unix-likes do it normally).
> Therefore there is no direct necessity for something like nohup.

You can also try and run in your ssh session:

```
START /B /MIN "cmd.exe" /C "myscript.bat"
```

And see if it survives the SSH closing event.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tried your way, but when I closed openssh, that exe was killed. My approach is to connect to windows through the ssh connection tool, and then execute (START /B /MIN cmd.exe /C "a.exe"). After the execution is successful, I close the openssh connection and the exe is killed

Comment: @Sunth Can you try to launch the nohup VB script instead of a.exe? As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66986585/6309.