# How can use Windows cmd/bat file to open various apps at once and close the terminal windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

I am using this:

```
start /b cmd /c "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
start /b  cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
start /b cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"
exit
```

The above works but keeps the prompt/terminal window open. How can I close it from inside the bat/cmd file as soon as the last app is open?

Comment: Use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536205/running-another-program-in-windows-bat-file-and-not-create-child-process

Comment: in most cases the CMD window will close automatically also you can add "@echo off" in the first line,this will reduces the complexity of the output although it would not matter in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
C:
cd \Windows
start notepad.exe
cd "\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
start chrome.exe
cd "\Program Files\Skype\Phone"
start Skype.exe
exit
```

it is probably the fact that your starting cmd - just start the application