# Running Start-Job from cmd.exe without having to wait with Wait-Job

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, process

I was assuming that it is possible to start a process in PowerShell using `Start-Job` without having to wait for its completion. But apparently is not the case when I'm starting PowerShell from `cmd.exe` because I have to use the `Wait-Job` cmdlet.

So I have two files:

**my-hook-runner.cmd**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\mydir\my-hook-ps.ps1
```

**my-hook-ps.ps1**

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { gci C:\mydir | Out-File C:\mydir\test.txt }
```

The script `my-hook-ps.ps1` creates a job and it adds the `test.txt` file when I run it from PowerShell console. But when I run `my-hook-runner.cmd` or `powershell.exe C:\mydir\my-hook-ps.ps1` in `cmd.exe`, the file `text.txt` is not added although the job is created.

It works when I pipe `Start-Job` into `Wait-Job` but this negates all the benefits of using these jobs because I have to wait for their completion.

Since the ps1 file is not executable on Windows, I have to start it from `cmd.exe`, and I want to spawn a detached process that lives on its own (because of this [Running another program in Windows bat file and not create child process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1536205/761095)).

The behavior is similar or identical to the one described at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a2c4741d-8c6b-4277-afcd-bbdc73ca8deb/startjob-works-from-powershell-but-not-from-cmd?forum=winserverpowershell.

I'd appreciate any comments, suggestions and also answers to the following questions:

- Why the PowerShell job works when I run it from PowerShell but does not work when I run it from `cmd.exe`? Is this about closing the job's PSSession when it hasn't yet finished running?
- Is it possible to start PowerShell jobs from `cmd.exe` without waiting for their completion?

Comment: It seems that I've solved my original problem with `powershell <path-to-ps1-file` and using `Start-Process` to launch new powershell instances. But the question about `Start-Job` remains. I'd like to know why it does not work without `Wait-Job` when started from `cmd.exe`.

Comment: When a parent process terminates all children processes will also terminate unless the children are run asynchronously.  So when your powershell terminates (parent) any spawn children will also terminate.

Comment: @jdweng even jobs terminate? I was assuming that the idea of a background job and ‘Start-Job’ is create independently running processes.

Comment: Where are you starting a "BACKGROUND PROCESS"?  When I said Asynchronously it is same as background job.  You are not starting a background job so when Powershell terminates so does the children.